# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

When I tried to run this:

```
p0 = Sequential()
p0.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size1, 50, weights=[embedding_matrix_passage], 
input_length=50, trainable=False))
p0.add(LSTM(64))
p0.add(Dense(256,name='FC1'))
p0.add(Activation('relu'))
p0.add(Dropout(0.5))
p0.add(Dense(50,name='out_layer'))
p0.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

q0 = Sequential()
q0.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size2,50,weights=embedding_matrix_query], 
input_length=50, trainable=False))
q0.add(LSTM(64))
q0.add(Dense(256,name='FC1'))
q0.add(Activation('relu'))
q0.add(Dropout(0.5))
q0.add(Dense(50,name='out_layer'))
q0.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model = concatenate([p0.output, q0.output])
model = Dense(10)(model)
model = Activation('softmax')(model)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
```

it's giving me this error:

```
AttributeError             
--->  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: As you define it, `model` is indeed a tensor, and not a model; you should switch all of your pipeline to the functional API - see [How to “Merge” Sequential models in Keras 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397258/how-to-merge-sequential-models-in-keras-2-0)

Comment: Yes, your whole code makes little sense, you should use the functional API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to use [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to create models with branches, multiple inputs/outputs. However, there is no need to do this for all of your code, just for the last part:

```
concat = concatenate([p0.output, q0.output])
x = Dense(10)(concat)
out = Activation('softmax')(x)

model = Model([p0.input, q0.input], out)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Interesting... So, we *can* use `p0.input` and `q0.input` in such a manner even if `p0` and `q0` are sequential models?

Comment: @desertnaut Sure, they are valid attributes because the corresponding models have been defined and also they are (placeholder) tensors after all.

Comment: A well-deserved upvote - seems you got both myself & Matias off-guard ;)