# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ListWrapper

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to concatenate/merge the Keras layers using `model.add(Concatenate([view1_model, view2_model]))`. My code raises `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ListWrapper` error.

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.layers import Dense, Concatenate
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.regularizers import l2

def create_model(layer_sizes1, layer_sizes2, input_size1, input_size2,
                    learning_rate, reg_par, outdim_size, use_all_singular_values):
    
    view1_model = build_mlp_net(layer_sizes1, input_size1, reg_par)
    view2_model = build_mlp_net(layer_sizes2, input_size2, reg_par)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Concatenate([view1_model, view2_model]))
    #model.add(Merge([view1_model, view2_model], mode='concat'))

    model_optimizer = RMSprop(lr=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss=cca_loss(outdim_size, use_all_singular_values), optimizer=model_optimizer)

    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':

    save_to = './new_features.gz'

    outdim_size = 10

    input_shape1 = 784
    input_shape2 = 784

    # number of layers with nodes in each one
    layer_sizes1 = [1024, 1024, 1024, outdim_size]
    layer_sizes2 = [1024, 1024, 1024, outdim_size]

    # the parameters for training the network
    learning_rate = 1e-3
    epoch_num = 100
    batch_size = 800

    # the regularization parameter of the network
    reg_par = 1e-5

    # specifies if all the singular values should get used to calculate the correlation or just the top outdim_size ones
    use_all_singular_values = False

    # if a linear CCA should get applied on the learned features extracted from the networks
    apply_linear_cca = True


    # Each view is stored in a gzip file separately
    data1 = load_data('noisymnist_view1.gz', 'https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~vnoroozi/noisy-mnist/noisymnist_view1.gz')
    data2 = load_data('noisymnist_view2.gz', 'https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~vnoroozi/noisy-mnist/noisymnist_view2.gz')

    # Building, training, and producing the new features by DCCA
    model = create_model(layer_sizes1, layer_sizes2, input_shape1, input_shape2,
                            learning_rate, reg_par, outdim_size, use_all_singular_values)
    #model.summary()
    model = train_model(model, data1, data2, epoch_num, batch_size)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/909436112.py in <module>
     47                             learning_rate, reg_par, outdim_size, use_all_singular_values)
     48     #model.summary()
---> 49     model = train_model(model, data1, data2, epoch_num, batch_size)
     50     model.summary()
     51     new_data = test_model(model, data1, data2, outdim_size, apply_linear_cca)

/tmp/ipykernel_27/2946459332.py in train_model(model, data1, data2, epoch_num, batch_size)
     28               batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epoch_num, shuffle=True,
     29               validation_data=([valid_set_x1, valid_set_x2], np.zeros(len(valid_set_x1))),
---> 30               callbacks=[checkpointer])
     31 
     32     model.load_weights("temp_weights.h5")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    758     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    759         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 760             *args, **kwds))
    761 
    762     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3064       args, kwargs = None, None
   3065     with self._lock:
-> 3066       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3067     return graph_function
   3068 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3461 
   3462           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3463           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3464           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3465 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3306             arg_names=arg_names,
   3307             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3308             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3309         self._function_attributes,
   3310         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)
   1005         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
   1006 
-> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1008 
   1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    669         return out
    670 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:787 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1037 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py:383 call
        outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1030 __call__
        self._maybe_build(inputs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:2659 _maybe_build
        self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/tf_utils.py:259 wrapper
        output_shape = fn(instance, input_shape)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/merge.py:496 build
        del reduced_inputs_shapes[i][self.axis]

    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ListWrapper
```

Comment: As someone commented on your last almost identical question an hour ago, this question is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397258/how-to-merge-sequential-models-in-keras-2-0

Comment: @KDecker this question is different from your link and is also different from my previous question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the Functionnal API of Keras instead of the Sequential API, where we need to define the inputs explicitly, make them pass to the model, and then build it. It would give a model similar to this one (with some adjustements):

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import  Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate

def create_model(layer_sizes1, layer_sizes2, input_size1, input_size2,
                    learning_rate, reg_par, outdim_size, use_all_singular_values):
    
    # check if right shape, or need to add a dim, like [input_size1, 1]
    input_1 = Input(shape=input_size1, name="input_1")
    input_2 = Input(shape=input_size1, name="input_2")
    # pass the inputs through the 2 models
    output_1 = build_mlp_net(layer_sizes1, input_size1, reg_par)(input_1)
    output_2 = build_mlp_net(layer_sizes2, input_size2, reg_par)(input_2)
    
    output_merged = Concatenate()([output_1, output_2])

    model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output_merged, name='my_model')

    model_optimizer = RMSprop(lr=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss=cca_loss(outdim_size, use_all_singular_values), optimizer=model_optimizer)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need it to be a sequential model.